# Watson Visual Recognition API - Invalid JSON content received using byte[]

Tags: java, watson, visual-recognition

I'm using java to call a VRA, but I got an issue using a byte[].

```
VisualRecognition service = new 
VisualRecognition(VisualRecognition.VERSION_DATE_2016_05_19);
service.setApiKey("{api-key}");
System.out.println("Classify an image");
ClassifyImagesOptions options = 
    new ClassifyImagesOptions.Builder()
        .images(new File(<<anyfile))
        .build();
VisualClassification result = service.classify(options).execute();
System.out.println(result);
```

This works fine, but if I change the File() to byte[] I got an error 
status: 400,

```
    "description": "Invalid JSON content received. Unable to parse.",
    "error_id": "parameter_error"
```

My code is just changing the File to a byte[] from the same image:

```
byte[] image = BufferedImage - from the same file;
ClassifyImagesOptions options = 
    new ClassifyImagesOptions.Builder()
        .images(image )
        .build();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post the relevant code: the code hidden behind "BufferedImage - from the same file", which is supposed to read the bytes of the file, and which is thus most probably the cause of your problem.

Comment: just looking at the API, it seems like `.images(image )` should take a second parameter with the name, like `.images(images, "dummyname.png")`